# Elixir Kafka client Elsa

Tags: apache-kafka, erlang, elixir

I am trying to create dynamically topics in Kafka but unfortunately some error occurs. Here is my code

```
  def hello_from_elsa do
    topic = "producer-manager-test"
    connection = :conn

    Elsa.Supervisor.start_link(endpoints: @endpoints,
         connection: connection)

    Elsa.create_topic(@endpoints, topic)
  end
```

As far as I understand I can connect to the broker itself but when the crete topic line is executed i get this error:

```
(MatchError) no match of right hand side value: false
    (kafka_protocol) src/kpro_brokers.erl:240: anonymous fn/1 in :kpro_brokers.discover_controller/2
    (kafka_protocol) src/kpro_lib.erl:376: :kpro_lib.do_ok_pipe/2
    (kafka_protocol) src/kpro_lib.erl:281: anonymous fn/3 in :kpro_lib.with_timeout/2
```

I am not sure whether i miss some additional step before creating the topic. But it should be fine I guess since i start the supervisor and its running :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say since the error is coming from the underlying Kafka protocol and not Elsa directly but it looks like there aren't any Kafka cluster controllers able to be found.

Topic management has to be done through a controller node so the `with_connection` function `create_topic` wraps explicitly passes the atom `:controller` to establish the connection and for whatever reason, likely something specific to your cluster, the function isn't able to successfully find a controller.

What type of cluster are you testing against? If you use the `divo` and `divo_kafka` library you can stand up a single-node kafka cluster using Docker on your local host to test against and it should work as expected.